# Neo4j-Store and retrieve images with cypher queries

Tags: image, neo4j, cypher

What is the best way to store images (binary arrays) in Neo4j?
I stored them as binary arrays but then how can I retrieve them with Cypher queries?
I have this query in which picture has been stored as binary arrays, but it seems there is an exception.

```
Match (n:`employees`) where employeeid='1' return n.picture
```

This is the full stack trace: (image size is 12Kb)

```
org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: Unhandled array type: class [B at
UnsupportedOperationException
   org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatchArray(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:720)
   org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatchNumberArray(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:715)
   org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatchByteArrayProperty(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:675)
   org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatchByteArrayProperty(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:280)
   org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatchPrimitiveArray(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:135)
   org.neo4j.server.helpers.PropertyTypeDispatcher.dispatch(PropertyTypeDispatcher.java:122)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.getRepresentation(CypherResultRepresentation.java:185)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.access$000(CypherResultRepresentation.java:38)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation$2$1.underlyingObjectToObject(CypherResultRepresentation.java:103)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation$2$1.underlyingObjectToObject(CypherResultRepresentation.java:99)
   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper.underlyingObjectToObject(IterableWrapper.java:57)
   org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.next(IteratorWrapper.java:47)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:64)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListSerializer.addList(ListSerializer.java:56)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.addTo(ListRepresentation.java:79)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:65)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:83)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat$1.write(OutputFormat.java:160)
   org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you try to use the transactional endpoint instead? Perhaps with the neo4j-jdbc driver? Or test it directly via curl? This issue is a bug in Neo4j-Server. You can raise it on github, but it is on a outdated endpoint so I'm not sure it's worth fixing.

Answer (score 2):

is that an actual cypher statement you are using? If so you just missed to type
WHERE n.empoyeeid="1"

Yes bytes is ok  (as []byte)
[Neo4j api docs](http://api.neo4j.org/2.0.1/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html)

But it is no GridFS or similar storage so if the blobs is big i would recommend using S3 or store on disk and just a pointer in the neo node. But again it should work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using java-rest bind api. So the actual code is: restresult = restengine.query("Match (n:`employees`) where employeeid='1' return n.picture", Collections.EMPTY_MAP) and it throws this exception: org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestResultException: Unhandled array type: class [B at. Any idea of what would be the solution?

Comment: Can you share the full stacktrace? Binary arrays over the wire are tricky anyway as JSON has no good support for binary data, if they are small perhaps just store base64 encoded strings. For larger ones I agree with Lundin, to just store an URL or file-name to a binary file (or a key into another blob store)

Comment: I added the full stack trace. What if I want to store them in nodes? Should I Encode them as strings?